# [Play Framework]: Performance testing with MySql

Tags: mysql, junit, playframework

I'm trying to implement play in my current job. And my manager asked me how would play framework deal with 1 millions records and MySql (I know that it is silly)...I've answered back that any problem JPA can address, PLAY also can... But he want some report...

So, I thought on creating a test method with play UnitTest... a simple query from the database with one million records in some table.

**Question: Is there some way to simulate one millon record in mysql database ?**

PS: I know that maybe it could not be a PLAY related question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this will help:

```
MyController extends Controller {
    public static void doInsert() {
        for (int i=0;i<1000000;i++) {
            final SampleEntity entity = new SampleEntity();
            entity.firstName = "First Name "+i;
            entity.anotherProperty = i;
            //etc
            entity.save();
        }
    }
}
```

You may need to deal a bit with flushing the connection every so often (this is from memory, may not be quite right) in order to avoid problems with Hibernate/JPA caching so many rows:

```
if (i % 50000 == 0) {
    em().flush();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Insert a million records into a table. It will take a few minutes at most. You can't simulate real performance without real data.